# I cannot connect to SQL Server contained on another Virtual Box

Tags: sql-server, virtualbox

Here is my troubleshooting list:

Troubleshooting to SQL VirtualBox

1. SQL allows remote connections. Done.
2. Enabled TCP for SQLServer.
3. Opened ports 1433 and 1434 in firewall.
4. Started SQLBrowser and SQLAgent.
5. Set all Virtual Boxes to use custom Nat Network, (can ping each other)
6. Added SQLAuthentication to new user BizTalkSQL - still could not connect.
7. Attempted to connect from VM10 (another VB) using SSMS - still could not connect.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on Stack Exchange by p.Campbell, that at least allowed my to connect to SQL Server on one virtual box from another virtual box, using SSMS. What was missing is that I needed to allow these two applications through the firewall.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\SqlServer.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\SqlBrowser.exe

Once I did that I was able to access SQL Server.